# Copying a databinding in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to change the Mode property of a databinding in code, but because databindings can't be changed after being set, I'm getting exceptions thrown. I was thinking of just making a copy of the databinding and using that, but the Binding class doesn't seem to be cloneable. Is there still a way to do it?

If the above is not practical to do, is there a minimum of properties that I can copy manually and have it work?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the code of your binding and what type you are binding to your datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this, but perhaps it's possible to use and clone a `BindingSource`?